# Required supply power for MAX11301

Tags: datasheet, maxim

I'm looking to use the MAX11301 for a project, in reviewing the datasheet i'm confused by exactly what the supply voltage required would be. I need to use some of the ports in the DAC analog output mode from 0-10V. I'm planning to supply the MAX11301 with 0 for AGND, DGND, and AVSSIO and +12V for AVDD, AVDDIO, and DVDD.

Will I be able to reliably have an analog output of 0-10V or is it required that AVSSIO be set to a value ~ -2V as the datasheet seems to suggest. Ideally I don't want to add the components to create the -2V supply.

Datasheet here: https://www.analog.com/en/products/max11301.html#product-overview

Answer (score 1):

A negative rail for a 0V output on a DAC is not at all an unusual requirement.  I've recently went through the same inquiry with an Analog Devices part (looking for actual specs, as I already had a small negative supply available).  An actual 'leg room' spec is hard to come by, as they typically specify a minimum nominal value (like -2V).

The table on Page 10 of the datasheet does confirm this:
[image]

and its note:

[image]

Considering that this is a low-resolution, 12-bit DAC, perhaps you can tolerate N-millivolts of zero-level-error?  Unless you meet the -2V Vavssio recommendation (and the +12V Vavddio), you would have to test for the levels, and there's no guarantee that the next chip you get would behave the same way.

Good luck!

-Chris

Comment: Yeah I saw that table in the datasheet which is what piqued my concern. Do you have any experience or ideas with how significant the zero-level error would be? Thanks for sharing your experience and advice

Comment: Well, it could be significant.  Starting off as non-linear, then just clipping.  I'm afraid that the whole 2V region is available for that to happen.  On both the top, and bottom rail.  You would have to try it, and then as mentioned above, the next chip you buy may be considerably different.